# Can nested list also be drag&droppable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-sortable-hoc

I use 'react-sortable-hoc'. I just wonder, can I make nested list also drag&droppable.... I have a drag&droppable list, which has listitems which on their own have nested lists...can I make that nested list drag&droppable too?

Answer (score 0):

> yes you can do it just follow below code
>
> import React, {Component} from 'react';

```
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import {SortableContainer, SortableElement, arrayMove} from 'react-sortable-hoc';

const SortableItem = SortableElement(({value}) => <li>{value}</li>);

const SortableList = SortableContainer(({items}) => {
    return (
        <ul>
            {items.map((value, index) =>
                <SortableItem key={`item-${index}`} index={index} value={value} />
            )}
        </ul>
    );
});

class SortableComponent extends Component {
    state = {
        items: ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3', 'Item 4', 'Item 5', 'Item 6']
    }
    onSortEnd = ({oldIndex, newIndex}) => {
        this.setState({
            items: arrayMove(this.state.items, oldIndex, newIndex)
        });
    };
    render() {
        return (
            <SortableList items={this.state.items} onSortEnd={this.onSortEnd} />
        )
    }
}

render(<SortableComponent/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

> for more details please follow link

[click here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multiple-react-sortable-hoc)

Comment: I use this package. I know how it works. Each my SortableElement is a Listitem, but there are cases, when Listitem has nested list, and my problem is to make this  nested lists draganddroppable too

Comment: see here is the example